# Equivalence of the Heine-Borel theorem for the set of rationals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

From the Heine-Borel theorem we can say that a subset $S$ of Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, the following two statements are equivalent:

- $S$ is **closed** and **bounded**.
- $S$ is **compact**, that is, every open cover of S has a finite subcover.

Would these statements still be valid in the set of rationals ($\mathbb{Q}$), or would there be any case that contradicts the statements?

Comment: No, as John Douma gave a counterexample in his answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need completeness for closed and bounded sets to be compact. Consider the set $\{p\in\mathbb Q: 0\le p^2\le 2\}$ as a counter-example.

Comment: If $\mathcal{K} = \{p \in \mathbb{Q}: 0 \leq p^2 \leq 2\}$, I could choose an open ball $O_n = B (r, p_n)$ (with $p_n \in \mathcal{K}$) such that $r <| p_ {n + 1} - p_n |$ (where $p_{n + 1}$ is the next element after $p_n$). So $\mathcal{K} \subset \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} O_n$, but does not admit a finite subcover. Would that be a good approach?